# How to to resize canvas objects to window size in tkinter without using object oriented programming?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

This is my code so far and I want to resize all of these widgets including the image to window size.

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.title("xxx")
win.geometry("600x600")
win.resizable()
w = 700
h = 700
x = 600 // 2
y = 600 // 2
canvas = Canvas(win, width=w, height=h, bg="grey")
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=50, pady=50)
img = PhotoImage(file="c.png")



canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 75, 500, fill="green")
canvas.create_rectangle(425, 0, 500, 500, fill="green")
canvas.create_rectangle(75, 0, 80, 500, fill="brown")

image = canvas.create_image(x, 440, image=img)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: tkinter does not include anything that will do this automatically. You will need to code in math yourself. You will need to use PIL to resize the image. Once you have the math you can trigger it with the <Configure> event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize all the items in the canvas using the `Canvas.coords(tagorId, x0, y0...)`. This can be used for any item in the canvas other than the image. For image use `Image.resize((x, y), resample)`.

Bind the `<Configure>` event to an event handler. So whenever the canvas is resized the event handler is called.

Here is a demo.(Note the other items on the canvas might be hidden by the image). The below code will automatically resize items to the canvas.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def resize_widgets(event):
    global resized 
    for items in canvas.find_all():
        if items != image:
            canvas.coords(items, 0, 0, event.width, event.height)

    resized = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.resize((event.width, event.height), resample = Image.NEAREST))
    canvas.itemconfig(image, image=resized)
    canvas.moveto(image, 0, 0)
    
win = Tk()
win.title("Dodge Car Challenger")
win.geometry("600x600")
win.resizable()
w = 700
h = 700
x = 600 // 2
y = 600 // 2

resized = None

canvas = Canvas(win, width=w, height=h, bg="grey")
#canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=50, pady=50)
canvas.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
canvas.bind('<Configure>', resize_widgets)

im = Image.open(r"your imagepath")
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)


canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 75, 500, fill="green")
item = canvas.create_rectangle(425, 0, 500, 500, fill="green")
canvas.create_rectangle(75, 0, 80, 500, fill="brown")

image = canvas.create_image(x, 440, image=img)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: @fkr19 do you see an image?

Comment: @fkr19 `canvas.create_rectangle(75, 0, 80, 500, fill="brown")` even this item is resized to the canvas. As I told in the answer, the above code will resize all the items on the canvas.